# If $x_n \to 0$ then does $\sum \frac{|x_n|}{n} $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am now thinking "No" but I cannot come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $x_n=\frac1{\log n}$?

Comment: Thank you for this. I spent a very long time trying go the other way.

Comment: The best known answer to this question.  $\sum\frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges.  But that is not the end: $\sum\frac{1}{n\log n \log\log n}$ diverges.  And so on.  There is no "slowest" divergent series, in the sense of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x_n=\dfrac1{\log n}$. You obtain a Bertrand's series
$\;\sum_{n\ge 2}\dfrac1{n^\alpha\log^\beta n}$ with $\alpha=\beta=1$.

It is known that a Bertrand's series converges if an only if $\alpha >1$ or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$. And specically this one, using the *integral test*.